# C# listen in tcp network without busyTimes?

Tags: c#, networking, stream, tcplistener

I am trying to catch all incoming events on a specific Port. It works fine but i think, my Socket is blocked for 5s while `stream.Read()` is performing. What could happen if a package enters while `stream.Read()` is busy? And how could i avoid possible dataloss?

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        System.Console.WriteLine("Testprogramm Connection\n");
        //ThreadListener tl = new ThreadListener();
        DateTime startTime3 = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime startTime4 = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan duration3;
        TimeSpan duration4;

        while (true)
        {
            DataPackage dp = Connection.readEvent(4002, 3000);

            DateTime EndZeit = DateTime.Now;
            if (dp.Ip.Equals("192.168.101.3"))
            {
                duration3 = EndZeit - startTime3;
                System.Console.WriteLine("Duration to last receive: " + duration3);
                startTime3 = DateTime.Now;
            }
            if (dp.Ip.Equals("192.168.101.4"))
            {
                duration4 = EndZeit - startTime4;
                System.Console.WriteLine("Duration to last receive: " + duration4);
                startTime4 = DateTime.Now;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    ...Connection.cs
    public static DataPackage readEvent(int port, int size)
    {
        DataPackage dp = new DataPackage();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        String ip_client = "";
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];
        try
        {
            System.Console.Write("Wait...:");
            listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
            listener.Start();
            tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
            tcpClient.Client.NoDelay = true;

            ip_client = tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

            stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;

            stream.Close();
            tcpClient.Close();
            listener.Stop();
            dp.Data = bytes;
            dp.setIP(ip_client);

            System.Console.Write("...received from " + ip_client + " busy:");
            TimeSpan duration = endTime - startTime;
            System.Console.WriteLine(duration.Seconds + "s");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            closeAllConnections();
            return null;
        }
        return dp;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not surprised that you're seeing the inter-event delays.  In your readEvent method, you're creating the sockets, then listening for an incoming connection, then performing your read() then closing all the sockets.  It takes a little bit of time to set up your sockets.  Its a better approach if you make the sockets members of your connection class, doing an initialization - create, listen, connect - and then in your readEvent method you would retrieve messages.  A fancier approach might be to queue up all the events so that clients of your connection could just go and pick them up, but that involves a little asynchronous programming.

```
     public class Connection : IDisposable {
    private readonly Queue<DataPackage> messages = new Queue<DataPackage>();

    public object syncLock = new Object();
    public List<DataPackage> GetCurrentMessages() {
        Monitor.Enter(syncLock);
        var result = new List<DataPackage>();
        try {
            foreach (var item in messages) {
                result.Add(item);
            }
            messages.Clear();
        } finally {
            Monitor.Exit(syncLock);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private TcpListener listener;
    private TcpClient tcpClient;
    private int bufferSize;
    private bool running;
    public void Init(int port, int size) {
        // not real thread safe here
        if (running) return;
        running = true;
        bufferSize = size;
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[1];
        listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
        listener.Start();
        listener.BeginAcceptSocket(ar => { 
            tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
            listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
            var t = new Thread(readEvent);
            t.Start();
        }, null);
    }

    private bool shouldRead = true;
    private void readEvent() {

        while (shouldRead) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

            try {
                Console.Write("Wait...:");

                var ip_client = tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

                var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
                var package = new DataPackage(); // add your stuff in here

                Monitor.Enter(syncLock);
                try {
                    messages.Enqueue(package);
                } finally {
                    Monitor.Exit(syncLock);
                }

                System.Console.Write("...received from " + ip_client + " busy:");
                TimeSpan duration = endTime - startTime;
                System.Console.WriteLine(duration.Seconds + "s");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

    }

    public class DataPackage {}

    #region IDisposable Members
    private bool disposed;
    void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (!disposed) {
            if (disposing) {
                shouldRead = false;
                tcpClient.Close();
                listener.Stop();
            }
            //Clean up unmanaged resources
        }
        disposed = true;
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: I have tried to init much as possible beforehand. But without noticing  some improvements. I have thought about threading, but i think there could be a problem with using a socket multiple times or multiple sockets linked to the same port...

Comment: I added an example that you might follow.  I whipped it up quick in VS, so it should compile, but it's not exactly tested.  You should get the idea from it.

Comment: i am currently trying this code. Previously rewriting all "var" and the "=>" for vs05. But it seams to stuck in an endless loop with the first read event. ![result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40030647/busy2.JPG).

Comment: Ahh, yeah.  Sorry the readEvent should have been private.  I probably gave you more than you were asking for with this example, but if you're going to be making networking applications you'll have to be aware of patterns like these.  What you should do is write your Main to into a loop where it checks Connection GetCurrentMessages method to see if anything has been sent.  Ending the loop would be up to you, but be sure to Dispose of the Connection object because it owns a long running thread.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are no any data loss. `Read` method in your case blocks thread until the first amount of data will come (even 1 byte). Theoretically you can wait infinite time, if client will keep "silence". If you want to limit wait time, use `tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout`, like this:

```
tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
```

So, there is everything quite right in your code, the problem is client keeps silence for 5 seconds.

PS: Why don't you use `IPAddress.Any` ? This `Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName())` may take a very long time in some cases.

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TCP listener may be waiting for the buffer to fill.

- Reduce the size of your buffer;
- Send packets with the [PUSH bit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758517%28WS.10%29.aspx) set; or
- Your client is waiting to build up a significant packet size.

To set the buffer size, use the [`TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivebuffersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

To avoid delays while waiting for the buffer to fill up, set the [`TcpClient.NoDelay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `true`.

Comment: I am not able to edit the clients sending procedure and i need this buffer size too obtain the whole package. TcpClient.NoDelay did not change anything

Comment: You may build up your payload incrementally; unless there's a specific reason, there's no need to make the buffer as big as your planned payload. For example, let's say your final payload is 1MB. Make the buffer size 64KB. You'll Read() 20 times; add each received partial payload to a local buffer.

Comment: Now, i get busytime 10s instead of 5s

Answer (score 0):

Use `TcpClient.Available` to see if enough bytes are available to read.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.available%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: TcpClient.Available return every times 0